# Issue with Purge command in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Pretty much, for some reason the actual purging works, but it wont send the response embed after its purged. Sometimes it does, sometimes it just spams terminal with errors.

Heres is my code:

```py
@tree.command(name= "purge", description="Purge messages in a channel", guild=discord.Object(id=guildId))
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(interaction, limit: int):
    await interaction.channel.purge(limit=limit)
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"Purged {limit} message(s)", color=0x3375FF)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

Honestly, im not too sure what is wrong with it. I tried it without an embed and that still didnt work.

https://pastebin.com/uibRCN1F Here is a link to the error I am getting in the termina

Comment: Just FYI; you need to place the triple backticks on a newlne for it to format it correctly.

Comment: "it sometimes errors" is not at all useful information, add the actual errors to your post...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your interaction is timing out. Perhaps try deferring and then using the `followup` property to send your message later.

```py
@tree.command(name= "purge", description="Purge messages in a channel", guild=discord.Object(id=guildId))
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(interaction, limit: int):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    await interaction.channel.purge(limit=limit)
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"Purged {limit} message(s)", color=0x3375FF)
    await interaction.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Nope, still seems to be spamming errors in console and not giving a response.

Comment: Okay; well can you tell us what those errors are? Put them in the question and we might be able to actually help rather than guessing.

Comment: Right; I think I figured it out. After some testing; I found that if I changed `interaction.followup.send` to `interaction.channel.send` then it works fine without any errors. I've modified my answer accordingly - hope that helps.